# Listing columns from multiple tables in sql

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by

I've got a database which is formed like this:

```
BOOKTYPES ( book_type_id (PK), book_type )
CATEGORIES ( category_id (PK), category )
PUBLISHERS ( publisher_id (PK), publisher, speciality, country )
BOOKS ( book_id (PK), title, publisher_id (FK), published_year,
purchase_price, category_id (FK),purchase_date, pages, 
book_type_id(FK) )
AUTHORS ( author_id (PK), first_name, last_name, pseudonym )
AUTHORSHIP ( author_id (PK), book_id (PK) )
```

Now, what I need help with is listing category and the number of books that contain that category. This means that I need to retrieve the category from CATEGORIES, and category_id from books. The problem I'm facing with this is that category_id already exists inside categories, and that isn't the one that I want to retrieve.

I'd really appreciate some help with this since it's been picking my brain for quite the while now.

Comment: Please include the queries you have tried, a sample of their results, and an explanation of what is wrong with the results.

Comment: Have you tried any queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> listing category and the number of books that contain that category

That looks like a simple aggregate query on `books`:

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(*) count_of_books FROM books GROUP BY category_id
```

If you want the category name as well, you can `JOIN` on `categories`. You do disambiguate the column names by prefixing them with the table they belong to (or the table alias):

```
SELECT c.category, COUNT(*)
FROM books b
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = b.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_id, c.category
```

To filter on a given count of categories, you can use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT c.category, COUNT(*)
FROM books b
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = b.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_id, c.category
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

Comment: But this does not list the name of the category though, what I'm having trouble with is combining the two.

Comment: Ah okay! I was having trouble understanding how I would use the join-function, but now I understand. Just one question, why do you assign category c, and books b? I understand that you use the letters in the join and group by statements, but why are they needed?

Comment: Also, if I were to order so that only categories with above 5 in the count id_list would come up, where would I put my WHERE statement?

Comment: So you do not have to use a WHERE clause then? @GMB

Comment: @Griezy: no, since you want to filter on an aggregated value (`COUNT(*)`), you need the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200365/discussion-between-griezy-and-gmb).